# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in QEMU when custom machine is added

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, qemu

I am trying to build a custom machine in QEMU for STM32 machine and  I have written a simple code to add the machine to the QEMU `-machine help` list. I have also written a code where I can add all peripherals (general file /main file)

But when I run the code I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. When I commented some part , I could pinpoint where I was getting the error:

```
static Property stm32f407_soc_properties[] = {
    DEFINE_PROP_STRING("cpu-type", struct stm32f407_soc,cpu_type),
    DEFINE_PROP_END_OF_LIST(),

};
```

I was getting the error when I fetch the `CPU-type`. Further when I debugged through GDB, it gave some information as below which I do not understand :

```
(gdb) run -machine stm32f407ve_scu -kernel test.elf
Starting program: /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-arm -machine stm32f407ve_scu -kernel test.elf
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffe7e4f700 (LWP 3487)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe764e700 (LWP 3490)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe69dc700 (LWP 3500)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe61db700 (LWP 3501)]

Thread 1 "qemu-system-arm" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555557ea571 in cpu_get_address_space (cpu=0x0, asidx=1) at /home/sups/Documents/stm32/qemu/exec.c:930
930     return cpu->cpu_ases[asidx].as;
(gdb) where
#0  0x00005555557ea571 in cpu_get_address_space (cpu=0x0, asidx=1) at /home/sups/Documents/stm32/qemu/exec.c:930
#1  0x00005555559700c6 in armv7m_load_kernel (cpu=0x0, kernel_filename=0x5555568afa00 "test.elf", mem_size=2097152)
    at /home/sups/Documents/stm32/qemu/hw/arm/armv7m.c:297
#2  0x0000555555999e3e in stm32f407ve_scu_init (machine=0x555556783f00) at /home/sups/Documents/stm32/qemu/hw/arm/stm32f407ve_scu.c:57
#3  0x0000555555ae9ed9 in machine_run_board_init (machine=0x555556783f00) at hw/core/machine.c:830
#4  0x0000555555a40372 in main (argc=5, argv=0x7fffffffde98, envp=0x7fffffffdec8) at vl.c:4516
```

I opened all the files mentioned in the errors above and checked what line the errors are and all these lines correspond to machine calls. But I do not know what should I be changing?

Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: I would consider it a QEMU bug. Try a different version?

Comment: Weird thing is it works for another custom machine that was added before. Do I still need to install and check with another version?

Comment: Your new code in stm32f407ve_scu_init() is passing a NULL pointer as the first argument to armv7m_load_kernel(), which is a bug in your code which eventually makes the code inside that function crash with a segmentation fault. You need to find out what you're doing wrong that means you don't have a valid pointer to the CPU.

Comment: armv7m_load_kernel(ARM_CPU(first_cpu), machine->kernel_filename, 2 * 1024 * 1024);
I'm sending the arguments as required by the syntax.
Could you also please explain how you came to this conclusion , so that I can understand it myself next time? Thanks

Comment: You can see in the backtrace the arguments to armv7m_load_kernel(), and that cpu=0x0. That is a bug in the calling code. If you're using "ARM_CPU(first_cpu)" as the argument, the problem is that you're calling armv7m_load_kernel() without having actually created any CPUs.